# Effect of discounting parameter on Language Model Perplexity

Tags: nlp, language-model

The general formula for absolute discounting for calculating language model probabilities subtracts a discounting parameter d from the count of the ngram before calculating the probabilities.

[image: LM with absolute discounting]

The perplexity of the model first decreases as d increases, and then later starts increasing again.

[image: Perplexity vs Discounting Parameter]

What is the reason behind this change? Why does the perplexity decrease first and then start increasing again?